# Is there a way to find arg_max() of a RandomForestRegressor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, random-forest

I'm using ML to predict a numerical output (a percentage from 0-100) from a number of (discretized) input variables. I want to find the combination of input variables that the model thinks will give the maximum output.

I have a fitted `RandomForestRegressor` model in Python (3.7.10), and currently evaluate the model's predictions for every combination of input variables.

```
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators ...)
modelfit = model.fit(a, b)
modelpredictions = model.predict(combinations)
```

However, this doesn't scale well with more variables/finer steps.

So, is there a simpler way to extract the global optimum of the model? E.g. an equivalent to `argmax()`.

Comment: Are you using the sklearn implementation of a RandomForestRegressor?

Comment: Yep, sklearn @André